# How do I grab specific strings from a source?

Tags: c#, json

I want to create an app that shows current information, i can get the information using a simple (at least, it looks pretty simple) API.

Now, you can use the API by going to the website, and enter the username. The URL will result in something like this `site.web/api/public/user?name=Usename`.
on that page is all the information I need, in form of one line of 'code'.

```
{"uniqueId":"hhus-7723dec98ecb9bc6643f10588e0bb3f4","name":"Username","figureString":"hr-125-40.hd-209-1369.ch-210-64.lg-270-1408.he-3329-1408-1408","selectedBadges":[],"motto":"sample txt","memberSince":"2012-08-25T14:01:04.000+0000","profileVisible":true,"lastWebAccess":null}
```

I want to extract this information and display it in my program, example:

```
{"uniqueId":"this is an ID"}
```

I only want the actual ID to be shown: this is an ID.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you're receiving is called [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). There are lots of libraries to read it easily, the most widely used in C# is [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

If you only need to extract one property, you can do something like this:

```
string json = ...
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
string uniqueId = obj["uniqueId"].Value<string>();
```

If you also need the other properties, it's probably easier to use deserialization: create a class with the same properties as the JSON object, and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to read the JSON into an instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks, finally figured it out :D

Answer (score 1):

The one line of code you're referring to is JSON data. It's stored in the format "key":"value","key:value","key:value" and so on.

You should take a look at Newtonsoft.Json which helps you do exactly this: parse JSON data :)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Answer (score 1):

Tying it all together for you...

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://site.web/api/public/user?name=Usename");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string userJson = reader.ReadLine();
reader.Close();

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(userJson);
string uniqueId = (string)jObject["uniqueId"];
```

Comment: I used the webclient to Download the json string and that didn't work for some reason, same for this. Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (463).      It works fine for other other api's such as facebook's... Just not for the website i'm using.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of Json. The most type safe way if to deserialize the data to a class you define.

Such a class could look like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string uniqueId { get; set; }
}
```

If you have the data in a string you can just deserialize it with the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package.

```
MyClass obj = JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyClass>(myJsonString);
```

If you get the data from http it is easier to use an client which can do the deserialization for you. Such a client is found in the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(myUrl);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    MyClass obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyClass>();
}
```

Of course this assumes the server is standards compliant and specifies it's content-type as application/json

Bonus: The classes you deserialize to can be auto generated from example at the site: http://json2csharp.com/ .